# PHP7 "class not found" ... why?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this:

In *app\Html\Controllers\Mail\MailerQueueController.php*:

```
 <?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Mailer;
 use App\Services\MailerService;
 $emails = \App\Services\JFIEmail::Query();    <-- class not found
```

In *app\Services\MailerService.php*:

```
 <?php
 namespace App\Services;
 class JFIEmail extends Email {
```

Throws: `class App\Services\JFIEmail not found`.

Why?

Comment: Please *do* note the backslash preceding "App". I don't know if that's the cause of the problem, but that is what I noticed.

Comment: Are you including the files? Just to be sure. with use App\Services\MailerService;  did you mean to include "App\Services\MailerService.php"; ?

Comment: Without the backslash, MC, it says `class App\Http\Controllers\Mailer\App\Services\JFIEmail not found.`  So, yes, it's necessary.  Thanks for asking.

Comment: Sar, this thing *(Laravel)* uses some kind of nifty autoloader.  Nothing anywhere in the code uses `include()` or `require()`.

Answer (score 4):

If your class is `App\Services\JFIEmail`, Composer will try to load `app/Services/JFIEmail.php`.

If your class is defined in `app/Services/MailerService.php`, that's not going to work.

Comment: Also `app\Html\Controllers\Mail\MailerQueueController.php` defines its namespace as `App\Http\Controllers\Mailer` which is not at all following [PSR-0 Autoloading standards](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Good catch.

Comment: *(Shrug ...)*  Yeah, there are a whole lot of things about "this old app" that can't even spell the word, "standard."  But, here I am.

Comment: Ceejayoz, notice that I *do* specify `use App\Services\MailerService` at the top of the queue-controller file.  The class is defined in that file, as you see.  I'll accept that it's trying to load the file.  But if for example I omit the path, it tries to use the controller's namespace.  When I tried `App\Services\MailerService\JFIEmail` it didn't work either.

Comment: @MikeRobinson `use` doesn't do what you think it does in that scenario.

Comment: Ceejayoz, I know what you're saying is true!  Howzabout editing your answer to tell me ... and the next guy ... *exactly* what is the error of my understanding?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: @MikeRobinson Re: your edited comment, the class namespace and the filesystem have to match. If you want to do `App\Services\MailerService\JFIEmail`, you need a file at `app/Services/MailerService/JFIEmail.php` that defines a class named `JFIEmail`. It's a direct one-to-one relationship.

Comment: I'm not finding case-sensitivity to be an issue.  It seems to be the namespace name that counts.  But, @ceejayoz, what you're suggesting here is that I move these "extra" class-definitions out of this file and into another one, say `App\Services\JFIEmail.php?`  Or, I expect, a subdirectory `App\Services\MailerService` containing two files:  `JFIEmail.php` and `MailerService.php`?

Comment: @MikeRobinson Case sensitivity will matter on a case-sensitive filesystem; if you're deploying to a Linux host (very common) it'll matter.

Comment: @MikeRobinson You can organize these any way you like, but the class's name and namespacing must match the filename and folder structure. `App\Foo\Bar` corresponds to `app/Foo/Bar.php`. One class definition per file.

Comment: @ceejayoz, well `use App\...` doesn't seem to mind that on this Linux the root directory-name is `app`.  In fact, it *specifically did not like* the fact that I had a lower-case `app\` when the namespace said `\App`!  Nonetheless, I've now implemented your suggestions and they work.  I'll write it up in a moment.  Thanks tremendously.

Comment: @MikeRobinson `App` versus `app/` is a special case defined by `composer.json`. See the line that says `"App\\": "app/"` in that file.

Answer (score 0):

With the gracious assistance of @ceejayoz, I resolved the problem as follows:

Instead of having multiple `class` definitions in one file, create a subdirectory `app\Services\MailerService` and in this directory place `JFIMail.php` and `MailerService.php,` each containing one class-definition that corresponds to the file-name.

The statement from the original post now reads:

```
 $emails = \App\Services\MailerService\JFIEmail::query();
```

And the `use` statements look like this:

```
 use app\Services\MailerService\JFIEmail;
 use app\Services\MailerService\MailerService;
```

---

*Interestingly,* and even though the name of the root-directory is `app` not `App`, PHP specifically rejected saying `app\Services\MailerService\JFIEmail`!  It wanted the *namespace* name to match exactly.   (However:  the names of all the inner folders do match case exactly, and I'm not going to explore the matter further.)

Again, thanks to everyone for their assistance in solving this one.

Comment: The reason for lowercase `app` is in `composer.json`, in the line that says `"App\\": "app/"`. It's basically aliased that way.